# how to decode json in scala with circe by ignoring fieldname case sensitivity

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have the following failing test case:

```
case class ActionRequest(action: String, `type`:String, key: String)

"Actions " should " be decoded correctly" in {
    val actionJson =
      """[
        |{"Action":"view","Type":"Product","Key":"1210"},
        |{"action":"filter","type":"by-price","key":"low-hi"}
        |]
        |""".stripMargin
    val actions = decode[List[ActionRequest]](actionJson).right.getOrElse(List())
    assert(actions.size == 2)
}
```

decoding fails with error:

```
LeftProjection(Left(DecodingFailure([A]List[A], List(DownField(action), DownArray))))
```

Is it possible for the decoder to map fields ignoring the case sensitivity?
Or maybe there is an elegant way handle this with decoder.prepare?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

object CirceApp extends App {

    val actionJson = """[
      {"Action":"view","Type":"Product","Key":"1210"},
      {"action":"filter","type":"by-price","key":"low-hi"}
    ]""".stripMargin

    case class ActionRequest(action: String, `type`: String, key: String)

    implicit val decodeActionJson: Decoder[ActionRequest] = (c: HCursor) => {
        val keysMapping = c.keys.get.groupBy(_.toLowerCase).map(kv => (kv._1, kv._2.head))
        for {
            actionField <- c.downField(keysMapping("action")).as[String]
            typeField <- c.downField(keysMapping("type")).as[String]
            keyField <- c.downField(keysMapping("key")).as[String]
        } yield {
          ActionRequest(actionField, typeField, keyField)
        }
    }

    println(decode[Seq[ActionRequest]](actionJson))
}
```

Comment: thanks for the anwser, but it's quite boilerplate'y to define mappings for every field, would be nice to just have some implicit way of mapping them instead

Comment: The code can be generalized using shapeless. I will try to provide an example in the next days. I don't think that it's possible without some boilerplate code.

Comment: ah ok, that would be interesting. Yes I guess preserving types requires explicit handling one way or another.